# ¿porque tengo este error? Error 1822: Failed to Add foreign key constraint Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un script donde todas las tablas están relacionadas. Crea la base de datos correctamente pero al ejecutar las tablas de pertenencias, transporte, entrada y salida me aparece un error.

```
CREATE DATABASE Sena;
Use Sena;


-- Tabla de Roles
CREATE TABLE Roles (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    rol VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE
);

-- Insertar roles permitidos
INSERT INTO Roles (rol) VALUES ('Aprendiz'), ('Instructor'), ('Funcionario'), ('Director'), ('Visitante');

-- Tabla de Aprendices
CREATE TABLE Aprendices (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    numero_ficha INT,
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_aprendices_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id)
);

-- Tabla de Instructores
CREATE TABLE Instructores (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    coordinacion VARCHAR(100),
    cursos_asignados TEXT,
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_instructores_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id)
);

-- Tabla de Funcionarios
CREATE TABLE Funcionarios (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    coordinacion VARCHAR(100),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_funcionarios_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id)
);

-- Tabla de Directores
CREATE TABLE Directores (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    privilegios VARCHAR(255),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_directores_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id)
);

-- Tabla de Visitantes
CREATE TABLE Visitantes (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    empresa_procedencia VARCHAR(100),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_visitantes_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id)
);

-- Tabla de Pertenencias
CREATE TABLE Pertenencias (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    descripcion VARCHAR(255),
    serial VARCHAR(50),
    usuario_id INT,
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_aprendiz FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Aprendices(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_instructor FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Instructores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_funcionarios FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Funcionarios(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_director FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Directores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_visitantes FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Visitantes(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- Tabla de Transporte
CREATE TABLE Transporte (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    placa VARCHAR(20),
    marca VARCHAR(50),
    color VARCHAR(50),
    tipo VARCHAR(50),
    usuario_id INT,
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_transporte_aprendiz FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Aprendices(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_transporte_instructor FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Instructores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_transporte_funcionario FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Funcionarios(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_transporte_director FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Directores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_transporte_visitante FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Visitantes(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- Tabla de Ingreso
CREATE TABLE Ingreso (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    usuario_id INT,
    rol_id INT,
    fecha DATE,
    hora_ingreso TIME,
    descripcion_motivo VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_aprendiz FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Aprendices(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_instructor FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Instructores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_funcionario FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Funcionarios(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_director FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Directores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ingreso_visitante FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Visitantes(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- Tabla de Salida
CREATE TABLE Salida (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    usuario_id INT,
    rol_id INT,
    ingreso_id INT,
    hora_salida TIME,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_aprendiz FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Aprendices(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_instructor FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Instructores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_funcionario FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Funcionarios(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_director FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Directores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_visitante FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Visitantes(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_salida_ingreso FOREIGN KEY (ingreso_id) REFERENCES Ingreso(id)
);
```

Cuando ejecuto las tablas de roles, aprendiz, instructor, funcionario y director se guardan correctamente, pero cuando quiero guardar las siguientes tablas me sale un error:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'fk_pertenencias_aprendiz' in the referenced table 'aprendices'   0.016 sec

He intentado hacer varios cambios y pero no consigo arreglar ese error.

Comment: 1.- No es necesario que agregues todo el código, basta con la sección que te arroja el error. Hasta donde veo, solo necesitas 3 tablas para replicar el error. Lee [mre] como guia. 2.- En Mysql según recuerdo, las columnas referenciadas deben estar indexadas, que es lo que menciona el error ´Missing index´, probaste agregar el index a la 2da columna referenciada ?

Comment: La llave primaria de la tabla aprendices es ID, por lo que no hace falta que incluyas ningún otro campo, ya que con el ID se puede identificar unívocamente al registro. La solución sería o cambiar la definición de la llave foránea, o cambiar la definición de la llave primaria de la tabla aprendices. Lo mismo te va a pasar con todas las otras tablas que tiene relacionadas esta.

Comment: Me parece que tienes un problema de diseño en tus tablas. En vez de tener una tabla por cada rol, necesitas una tabla general de personas. ¿Qué pasará cuando los aprendices dejen de ser aprendices y se vuelvan instructores? ¿O que pasará con cualquier otro cambio de rol? Con el diseño actual perderías todo el historial de la persona o tendría 2 o más roles a la vez. Hay otros problemas, pero ese es el más grave.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tus llaves foráneas en la tabla de pertenencias (y las subsecuentes) usan 2 columnas: `usuario_id` y `rol_id`. Mientras que tus tablas de referencia solo usan una columna que hace referencia al id de usuario.

Esto se puede solucionar fácilmente asignando las 2 columnas a la llave primaria.

```
-- Tabla de Roles
CREATE TABLE Roles (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    rol VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE
);

-- Insertar roles permitidos
INSERT INTO Roles (rol) VALUES ('Aprendiz'), ('Instructor'), ('Funcionario'), ('Director'), ('Visitante');

-- Tabla de Aprendices
CREATE TABLE Aprendices (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    numero_ficha INT,
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_aprendices_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id),
    CONSTRAINT pk_aprendices_id_rol PRIMARY KEY(id, rol_id)
);

-- Tabla de Instructores
CREATE TABLE Instructores (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    coordinacion VARCHAR(100),
    cursos_asignados TEXT,
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_instructores_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id),
    CONSTRAINT pk_instructores_id_rol PRIMARY KEY(id, rol_id)
);

-- Tabla de Funcionarios
CREATE TABLE Funcionarios (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    coordinacion VARCHAR(100),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_funcionarios_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id),
    CONSTRAINT pk_funcionarios_id_rol PRIMARY KEY(id, rol_id)
);

-- Tabla de Directores
CREATE TABLE Directores (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    privilegios VARCHAR(255),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_directores_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id),
    CONSTRAINT pk_directores_id_rol PRIMARY KEY(id, rol_id)
);

-- Tabla de Visitantes
CREATE TABLE Visitantes (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    empresa_procedencia VARCHAR(100),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_visitantes_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(id),
    CONSTRAINT pk_visitantes_id_rol PRIMARY KEY(id, rol_id)
);

-- Tabla de Pertenencias
CREATE TABLE Pertenencias (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    descripcion VARCHAR(255),
    serial VARCHAR(50),
    usuario_id INT,
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_aprendiz FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Aprendices(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_instructor FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Instructores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_funcionarios FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Funcionarios(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_director FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Directores(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_visitantes FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id, rol_id) REFERENCES Visitantes(id, rol_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Sin embargo, te recomiendo ampliamente que normalices mejor tus tablas. Este ejemplo es un inicio pero sin conocer a profundidad tu proyecto, puede ser un punto de partida.

```
-- Tabla de Roles
CREATE TABLE Roles (
    rol_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_rol VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE
);

-- Insertar roles permitidos
INSERT INTO Roles (nombre_rol) VALUES ('Aprendiz'), ('Instructor'), ('Funcionario'), ('Director'), ('Visitante');

CREATE TABLE Usuarios(
    usuario_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    numero_documento VARCHAR(20),
    nombre_completo VARCHAR(100),
    contacto_telefonico VARCHAR(20),
    direccion_residencia VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    rol_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_rol FOREIGN KEY (rol_id) REFERENCES Roles(rol_id),
    CONSTRAINT pk_usuarios_id PRIMARY KEY(usuario_id)
);    

-- Tabla de Aprendices
CREATE TABLE Aprendices (
    usuario_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    numero_ficha INT,
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_aprendices FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id) REFERENCES Usuarios(usuario_id)
);

-- Tabla de Instructores
CREATE TABLE Instructores (
    usuario_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    coordinacion VARCHAR(100),
    cursos_asignados TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_instructores FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id) REFERENCES Usuarios(usuario_id)
);

-- Tabla de Funcionarios
CREATE TABLE Funcionarios (
    usuario_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    centro_formacion VARCHAR(100),
    coordinacion VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_funcionarios FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id) REFERENCES Usuarios(usuario_id)
);

-- Tabla de Directores
CREATE TABLE Directores (
    usuario_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    privilegios VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_directores FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id) REFERENCES Usuarios(usuario_id)
);

-- Tabla de Visitantes
CREATE TABLE Visitantes (
    usuario_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    empresa_procedencia VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT fk_usuarios_visitantes FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id) REFERENCES Usuarios(usuario_id)
);

-- Tabla de Pertenencias
CREATE TABLE Pertenencias (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    descripcion VARCHAR(255),
    serial VARCHAR(50),
    usuario_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_pertenencias_usuario FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES Usuarios(usuario_id)
);
```